# EmberJS: How to make the carousel to work

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, bootstrap-carousel

I've installed `ember-bootstrap` add-on, and have tried doing it the bootstrap way. It didn't work.

Then used `slick-carousel` as well `ember-carousel`, but neither of them seem to work properly. `ember-carousel` renders oddly both the rich and regular form.

The `slick carousel` works but none of the properties seem to work properly.

Anybody have any surefire ways to get a carousel in ember to work properly?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest **code** necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `carousel.js` (or bootstrap.js) as `app.import()` statement to the `ember-cli-build.js`.

From [bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-individual-compiled):

> Plugins can be included individually (using Bootstrap's individual
>   *.js files), or all at once (using bootstrap.js or the minified bootstrap.min.js).